# sudo rsync -a doesn't preserve ownership nor permissions

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-18.04

I really have no clue what I am doing wrong. I want to backup my SSD to an external HDD using rsync. I have several users using the SSD and I need to preserve all ownership and permissions. So I'm using "rsync -a". However using "sudo rsync -a" results in changed ownership on target device. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my call:

```
sudo rsync -av --progress /media/mschoenebeck/satassd1t /media/admin/usbhdd8t
```

And this is what happens:

[image]

Comment: What is the filesystem on the target device? What mount options are you using to mount it?

Comment: Filesystem on all drives is ext4. `$ cat /proc/mounts` shows `/dev/sdb2 /media/mschoenebeck/usbhdd8t ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,stripe=8191,data=ordered 0 0`